# What is $1 and $2 in Regular Expressions?

Tags: c#, regex

What is $1 and $2 in C# regular expression? Does both come under groups?

Comment: FYI, those are part of the .NET regular expression syntax. C# has no support for regular expressions. All regular expression support is part of the .NET Framework.

Comment: Please put a sample of your regex. The $1, $2, $, could mean different thing depending the context where you are using it.

And @JohnSaunders is right.

Comment: @celerno Is $1 ever anything other than a numbered group substitution?

Answer (score 21):

That is values of captured groups by index. $1 is a first captured group, and $2 is a second captured group. As David pointed, these values used in replacement patterns.

```
string input = "Hello World";
string result = Regex.Replace(input, @"(\w+) (\w+)", "$2 $1");
```

Output: `World Hello`

Answer (score 4):

These are [substitutions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0.aspx). Specifically [numbered group substitutions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0.aspx#Numbered). From the documentation:

> The $number language element includes the last substring matched by
>   the number capturing group in the replacement string, where number is
>   the index of the capturing group. For example, the replacement pattern
>   $1 indicates that the matched substring is to be replaced by the first
>   captured group. For more information about numbered capturing groups,
>   see Grouping Constructs in Regular Expressions.
>
> Capturing groups that are not explicitly assigned names using the
>   (?) syntax are numbered from left to right starting at one.
>   Named groups are also numbered from left to right, starting at one
>   greater than the index of the last unnamed group. For example, in the
>   regular expression (\w)(?\d), the index of the digit named
>   group is 2.
>
> If number does not specify a valid capturing group defined in the
>   regular expression pattern, $number is interpreted as a literal
>   character sequence that is used to replace each match.
>
> The following example uses the $number substitution to strip the
>   currency symbol from a decimal value. It removes currency symbols
>   found at the beginning or end of a monetary value, and recognizes the
>   two most common decimal separators ("." and ",").
>
> ```
> using System;
> using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
>
> public class Example
> {
>    public static void Main()
>    {
>       string pattern = @"\p{Sc}*(\s?\d+[.,]?\d*)\p{Sc}*";
>       string replacement = "$1";
>       string input = "$16.32 12.19 £16.29 €18.29  €18,29";
>       string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement);
>       Console.WriteLine(result);
>    }
> }
> // The example displays the following output: 
> //       16.32 12.19 16.29 18.29  18,29
> ```

Comment: Can you please explain the example in the following link? [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1.aspx) _Secound example_ **line** `string replacement = "$2";`

Comment: That's explained in the first paragraph of the documentation that I quote in the answer. `$1` is the first captured group, `$2` is the second captured group and so on.