# Regex remove 2 sections of url at once

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I have these possible urls:

```
https://letterboxd.com/username/film/sometitle/
https://letterboxd.com/username59/film/sometitle/1/
https://letterboxd.com/username59/film/sometitle/2/
```

I want them all to display like this, without the username and without the trailing number if there is one:

```
https://letterboxd.com/film/sometitle/
```

**✔** I can remove the trailing number, where it exists, with this:

```
=IF(REGEXMATCH(A2,"/film/(.*?)/\d/"), left(A2,len(A2)-2), A2)
```

result: `https://letterboxd.com/username59/film/sometitle/`
I have to be careful here because if a film's title is just a digit, I don't want it to be replaced, so I specified that there had to be content between /film/ and the trailing digit. (eg, I have to distinguish between `film/9/` and `film/sometitle/9/`

**✔**  I can remove the username with this (although I'll probably have to also account for other types of characters, come to think of it):

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A2, regexextract(A2, "\/[A-Za-z0-9]+\/"),"/")
```

result: `https://letterboxd.com/film/sometitle/2/`

❌ But I can't for the life of me figure out how to combine both to do it all in one formula! I can perform one of the formulas on the results of the other one, but I can't combine to have it all done in one fell swoop.  I've tried too many combinations to list here, but this one I thought was the most promising:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A2, REGEXEXTRACT(IF(REGEXMATCH(A2,"/film/(.*?)/\d/"), left(A2,len(A2)-2), A2),"\/[A-Za-z0-9]+\/"),"/")
```

result: `https://letterboxd.com/film/sometitle/2/`

It didn't take care of the trailing `2/` and I don't know why. I'm guessing it's to do with some form of circularity? or the order of things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
=REGEXREPLACE(A2, "\/[^\/]+(\/film\/[^\/]+\/)[\d\/]*", "$1")
```

You can see the [regex match pattern here](https://regex101.com/r/1Vn44G/1).

[image]

Comment: You can save demos on regex101, post link to the demo, instead of positng a picture.

Comment: I've added a link

Comment: Worked like a charm. Aside from the regular expression (thank you), my issue with the regexreplace was always what to replace it *with*. That "$1" did the trick. I've never encountered it before. Is it easy to explain?

Comment: I found [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19141069/what-is-1-and-2-in-regular-expressions) this as an explanation.

Comment: I’m pretty sure that you don’t need all those back slashes escaping forward slashes; the forward slash has no special meaning in regex - it’s just a literal character and escaping it has no effect, except to make the regex harder to read (multiple escaped slashes is called “chainsaw” regex by some due to its appearance). However *some* languages use the forward slash as a delimiter (eg JS). Judging by the [official documentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034332?hl=en), google sheets is not one of those languages, so you can remove all the backslashes and it will work.

Comment: @Bohemian, you are so right. Final formula without the backslashes looks like this, is easier to read, and works great:  `=REGEXREPLACE(A2, "/[^/]+(/film/[^/]+/)[\d/]*", "$1"`

Comment: @lise "$1" is a backreference for the first capture group. ($2, etc. will work for the second, etc). It seems Google's escaping requirements are different, anyway, the concept is the same!

Answer (score 1):

This regex should match what you need. The main assumption is that you don't need anything after third `/` following the TLD.

```regex
(https?\:\/\/(?:\w*?\.\w+?)*\/(?:.*?\/){3})
```

- `https?\:\/\/(?:\w*?\.\w+?)` This portion is for the url and TLD.
- `*\/(?:.*?\/){3}` This captures anything up until the 3rd `/` and nothing after that.

Instead of replacing, you should be able to just match with the above regex to get the values you want.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative (non-regex) way, may be:

```
=substitute(join("/", query(split(A2, "/"), "Select Col1, Col2, Col4, Col5"))&"/", ":", ":/")
```

and see if that works?

Comment: Indeed it does work. It never occurred to me to use query in this way; I tend to reserve it to display info from other sheets. This opens up lots of possibilities! Is query more resource intensive than regex?

Answer (score 1):

You could use 2 capturing groups to capture what you want to keep and use the 2 groups in the replacement.

Then match what you don't want to keep, which will be from the first forward slash and the part that comes after it until the next forward slash and match an optional forward slash and 1 or more digits at the end.

```
(https?:\/\/[^\/]+)\/[^\/]+(\/film\/[^\/]+)(?:\/\d+)?
```

**Explanation**

- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `https:\/\/[^\/]+` Match `http`, optional s and `://`. Then 1+ times any char except `/`
- `)` Close group 1
- `\/[^\/]+` Match `/` and 1+ times any char except `/`
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `\/film\/[^\/]+` Match `/film/` and 1+ times any char except a `/`
- `)` Close group 2
- `(?:\/\d+)?` Match optional `/` and 1+ digits

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qx6Ari/1)

In the replacement use

```
$1$2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regex which works:

```
https:\/\/([^\/]+)\.com/([^\/]+)/([^\/]+)/([^\/]+)/((\d)+\/)?
```

From this you get:

Group1 : `letterboxd.com`

Group3 : `film`

Group: `sometitle`

Answer (score 0):

This regex also match what you need:

```
   C4=REGEXREPLACE(A4,"(\/user[^\/]+|\d+\/$)","")
```

[Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/qx6Ari/2)

1. `/user[^\/]+` -> match from username... until "/"
2. `\d+\/$` -> match last number at the end of string.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hmm. This doesn't work for me; I keep being asked for a 3rd argument (the replacement text). I wonder how you got around that

Comment: yes, 3rd argument is "" ,It is the default . If not, just create a custom function